# init a Map <Foo,Vector<Bar>> - Java 7

Tags: java

I need to initialize a like `Map x<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>` it allows me if I `@override` the Map methods

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The type new Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>.isEmpty()   Repository.java /proj_individual/src/repo   line 12 Java Problem
The type new Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>.size()  Repository.java /proj_individual/src/repo   line 12 Java Problem
The type new Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>.keySet()    Repository.java /proj_individual/src/repo   line 12 Java Problem
The type new Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>.remove(Object)  Repository.java /proj_individual/src/repo   line 12 Java Problem
The type new Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>.entrySet()  Repository.java /proj_individual/src/repo   line 12 Java Problem
The type new Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>.putAll(Map<? extends Apartment,? extends Vector<Expense>>)  Repository.java /proj_individual/src/repo   line 12 Java Problem
The type new Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>.values()    Repository.java /proj_individual/src/repo   line 12 Java Problem
The type new Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>.clear() Repository.java /proj_individual/src/repo   line 12 Java Problem
The type new Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>.get(Object) Repository.java /proj_individual/src/repo   line 12 Java Problem
The type new Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>.containsKey(Object) Repository.java /proj_individual/src/repo   line 12 Java Problem
The type new Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>.containsValue(Object)   Repository.java /proj_individual/src/repo   line 12 Java Problem
The type new Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Map<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>.put(Apartment, Vector<Expense>) Repository.java /proj_individual/src/repo   line 12 Java Problem
```

But I read on the internet that Map isn't a interface, it is a class, am I doing it wrong, or this is the way it has to be done?

Comment: Umm.. What? `Map is a class` - You read this on internet?

Comment: Map is an interface.
(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: What about `Map<Apartment, Vector<Expense>> myMap = new HashMap<Apartment, Vector<Expense>>()` ? And have a look at JB Nizets answer. There you find all information you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Map<Apartment, Vector<Expense>> map = new HashMap<Apartment, Vector<Expense>>();
```

`Map` is an interface (as [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) says — javadoc should be your reference, rather than the Internet). You need to choose an implementation (HashMap being the most often used one, but there are other implementations, with other characteristics).

You should also forget about Vector. It shouldn't be used anymore. Use List as a type, and ArrayList as an implementation (there are also other List implementations, but ArrayList is almost always what you want):

```
Map<Apartment, List<Expense>> map = new HashMap<Apartment, List<Expense>>();
```

or simply

```
Map<Apartment, List<Expense>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

if you're under Java 7.

Comment: Java 7, may as well use the `<>` operator

Comment: I added that in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ty, sorry if answeres are for dummies, but just getting used to java, sometime i don't know where i can find exactlly what I need

Comment: so if u are learning this Links should help you: [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) for your current issue or this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) for everything else

Answer (score 3):

> But I read on the internet that Map isn't a interface

The best place for information about a programming language will always be the official documentation. Speaking of java, just make sure to look first at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/

[Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is an interface. From the Java docs API:

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.
>   This interface takes the place of the Dictionary class, which was a totally abstract class rather than an interface.

I recommend you to use one of the implementing classes like [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). From the Java API docs:

> Hash table based implementation of the Map interface. This implementation provides all of the optional map operations, and permits null values and the null key. (The HashMap class is roughly equivalent to Hashtable, except that it is unsynchronized and permits nulls.) This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Your code could be then be functional by simply replacing `Map` for `HashMap` as in:

```
new HashMap<Apartment,Vector<Expense>>
```

I hope it helped. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Please check here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

You can use a HashMap to instantiate.